# PHP how to truncate an array

Tags: php

How do you truncate a PHP array in a most effective way?

Should I use [array_splice](http://de.php.net/array_splice)?

Comment: What do you want to achieve ? Provide some example.

Comment: Why the aversion to `array_splice`?

Comment: I read an SQL join result and need to reset an associative array every 3rd iteration. I thought count could be used here, like in some languages where you set array length to 0...

Comment: PHP's array length is just metadata. It's basically read-only. To affect it, you have to actually add/remove elements.

Comment: I must **really** be missing the point of this question. If you want to set the length to 0, wouldn't it just be `$result=array();`

Comment: No, because `$result=array();` would a) allocate a new array b) drop for garbage collection the old array. So it wouldn't be an efficient way to truncate a PHP-array.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use the native functions to remove array elements:

- [array_pop](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php) - Pop the element off the end of array
- [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) - Shift an element off the beginning of array
- [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) - Extract a slice of the array
- [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) - Remove one element from array

With this knowledge make your own function

```
function array_truncate(array $array, $left, $right) {
    $array = array_slice($array, $left, count($array) - $left);
    $array = array_slice($array, 0, count($array) - $right);
    return $array;
}
```

<strike>Demo - http://codepad.viper-7.com/JVAs0a</strike>

Comment: Peter can you explain whats `$left` and `$right` parameters for

Comment: @RahilWazir truncate x `$left` elements from left, truncate x `$right` parameters from right

Answer (score 4):

Yes, unless you want to loop over the array and [unset()](http://php.net/unset) the unwanted elements.

Comment: Note, in a foreach you would have to use the full array index reference since foreach uses a copy of the array. `foreach($array as $key => $value ) { unset($array[$key] }` not `foreach($array as $key => $value )  { unset($value) }`. The second one just unsets the copy.

Answer (score 2):

This function should work

```
function truncateArray($truncateAt, $arr) {
    array_splice($arr, $truncateAt, (count($arr) - $truncateAt));
    return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of this functions:

```
function array_truncate(&$arr)
{
    while(count($arr) > 0) array_pop($arr);
}
// OR (faster)
function array_truncate2(&$arr)
{
    array_splice($arr, 0, count($arr));
}
```

Usage:

```
$data2 = array("John" => "Doe", "Alice" => "Bob");
array_truncate($data2);
// OR
array_truncate2($data2);
```

Comment: The `while`-loop would probably be the most inefficient way to truncate an array :-)

Comment: @AlexanderFarber of course it is, that's why i said (in the comment) that the other is faster. I included to array_pop method to show a method where you have the option to do something to the element before discarding it.

Answer (score 0):

effectiveness (performance?) depends on which side you wish to truncate (the start or the end) and how many elements you wish to truncate and how big is array.

1. truncate few elements from the end - `unset()`
2. truncate few elements from the start - `array_shift()`
3. truncate many elements from any side - re-assigning (re-creating) with `array_slice()`

these are for index-based arrays of common size, about 100 elements or so, ordered by "effectiveness". `array_splice()` is used to remove (and re-index) or replace elements (and re-index, when counts dont match) in the array, so it doesn't fit in "truncate" category. i prefer to use this function only for a single element - to remove it.

to equalize (1) and (2) one may posses `SplDoublyLinkedList`.