# Adding 52 0's at the end of each array

Tags: php, arrays

is there a better way of doing this ? i need 52 0's at the end of each array
I already tryd to make a array and implode it but then it behaves like a string.

```
for($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++)
    {       
        array_push($totaal["week".$i], 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    }
```

Comment: This looks like a code smell. I can't say for sure, as I don't know much about the context of this code, but you're going to end up with a very large data structure that is mostly empty. You may benefit from spending a little time thinking if there's an alternative way to achieve your goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$zeros_array = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++)           
   array_push($zeros_array, 0);

for($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++)       
   $totaal["week".$i] = array_merge($totaal["week".$i], $zeros_array);
```

Comment: Or even better: `$zeros_array = array_fill(0, 52, 0);`

Comment: Thanks mate, dindt know it was that simple. I will answer this asap

Comment: Is there also a function that you can limit youre array ? for example array keys 0, 52

Comment: What do you mean by limiting?

Comment: now i am putting 52 0's at the end of each array. my last array will have 109 keys, i want to limit it to 52 keys

Comment: @Julez look at `array_pad` to add zeros, and limit the total

Comment: `array_pad` can help you, also look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985416/php-how-to-truncate-an-array, here are various techniques to truncate array in PHP

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the zeroes into their own array and then merge it with each in turn. This should be more efficient.

```
$zeroes = array_fill(0, 52, 0);
for($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++)
{       
    $totaal["week".$i] = array_merge($totaal["week".$i], $zeroes);
}
```

Comment: `array_merge` function does not modifies original array, but returns the new one.